# Prove $E(t^X)=\frac{p^2qt^3}{1-t+pqt^2-pq^2t^3}.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value, conditional-probability

> A rare coin is repeatedly tossed, where $P(H)=p=1-q$. Let X be the number of spins until HTH appears for the first time, and Y the number of spins until HTH or THT appears. Prove that $$\mathbb{E}(t^X)=\frac{p^2qt^3}{1-t+pqt^2-pq^2t^3}.$$
> Calculate $\mathbb{E}(t^Y)$.

I've been dealing with this problem all afternoon and I can't get to any results, so I turn to you for help. Any suggestion will be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate more please, it's my first probability course and I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Have you seen similar questions? This question is probably meant to be solved by recursion i.e. relating $E[t^X]$ to itself via observing recent coin tosses.

Comment: Represent the game by a Markov chain with states $H$, $T$, $HT$, $HTH$. The initial distribution is $u = \begin {pmatrix} p & q & 0 \end {pmatrix}$. The transition matrix is
$$\begin {pmatrix}
p & 0 & q & 0 \\
p & q & 0 & 0 \\
0 & q & 0 & p \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end {pmatrix}.$$
If the upper-left $3 \times 3$ matrix is $P$ and the upper-right $3 \times 1$ vector is $ v$, then
$$\mathbb P(X = k) = u P^{k - 2} v, \\
\mathbb E(s^X) = s^2 u (I - s P)^{-1} v.$$
For the second problem, you'll have five states $H$, $T$, $HT$, $TH$, $HTH \lor THT$.